# Details about html validator

Tags: html

I need to know the reason why we use or rely on html validator for html?? I guess it doesnt meet our requirements of the browser compatibility.. Or else what is the use of this HTML Validator??

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html)
 attempts to answer the questions many people have regarding why they should bother with Validating their web sites and tries to dispel a few common myths.

Comment: @Sachindra Some additional appropriate information is available also at this page [Why Validate Your Pages?](http://www.htmlvalidator.com/htmlval/whyvalidate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will 'cheat' the established standards and render erroneous HTML in a way that looks OK visually. An HTML validator can tell you whether or not your page actually conforms to the standard, giving you peace of mind into the future (of possibly stricter browsers).

Answer (score 0):

HTML interpretation is sloppy as crap.  There is a significant amount of garbage that HTML processors with interpret when they shouldn't.  This means problems that should destroy a HTML document will be processed anyways resulting in malformed content or function features that do not resemble their intended objectives.  Some of these behaviors include unquoted attributes that cause problems if attribute values collide with attribute names or contain spaces or so forth.  Missing ending tags can cause all sort of problems.  Honestly, a browser should reject processing of pages that are so broken, but they won't.  Instead they will perform any level of defamation that your horrible HTML code will allow them to render.

By validating your code avoids these destructive syntax problems.  Validation is necessary, because if the browser is willing to processing any level of garbage that it can then it is certainly not going to warn of you problems, so there is no way to know there are problems unless the code is validated.